# Doesn't $S_3$ have 5 proper subgroups and not 4?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In Michael Artin's "Algebra," he writes, "The group $S_3$ has six subgroups, four of them proper."

However, I counted 5 proper subgroups. What did Artin mean by that statement?

[image]

Comment: Most probably good'old Michael means "proper **non-trivial** " subgroups...

Comment: Yes, his definition of "proper" excludes the whole group and the trivial subgroup. In the first edition, this definition is on page 45.